# Multilevel or HLM model instead of two step estimation

Tags: multilevel-analysis, hierarchical-bayesian

I have a two-stage regression model as follows:

Yij=XijB+uij,
B=ZjR+Mj+ej.
where I first the parameters B by linear regression (OLS), then secondly the B estimate is regressed on Zj and Mj to capture the variation of B (moderation effect), using WLS.

However, I want to do this in a single step, using HLM/multilevel models.
Any suggestions on how I can do this in R?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site, Saeid. This is definitely an analysis well-suited to multilevel models. In R, you can use the `lme4` package to estimate such models using maximum likelihood. In your case, you can use the following formula to test whether the slope effect of B on $Y_{ij}$ is further dependent on $Z_j$ and $M_j$:

```
require(lme4)
m1 <- lmer(y ~ B + B*Z + B*M + (B | ClusterID), data=df)
```

The `(B | ClusterID)` code represents the random effects of interest. Here you are allowing the slope of B to vary across the different clusters in your data. The multilevel model does not estimate a separate slope for each Cluster; rather it estimates a variance term for the B slope (and a covariance beween B and the cluster intercepts) that quantifies the variance of B slopes around the fixed effect estimate of B.

The two interaction terms are what allow you to explain slope variation across clusters. They address whether the heterogeneity in B slopes observed across clusters are explained by the cluster-level predictors $Z_j$ and $M_j$.